# input is number of elements the program should print

Tags: java, integer, sequence, element

I would like to write a program that prints a sequence of integer numbers written in a single line with the numbers space-separated. The input of the program is a positive integer called n, this is the number of the elements of the sequence the program should print.

For example, if n = 7, then the program should output 1 2 2 3 3 3 4.

**THIS IS MY CODE:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        n = scanner.nextInt();
        while (n == 0) {
            n = scanner.nextInt();
            for (int i = n; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.println(i * n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

yeah I have no clue, that's why I am asking for help ;)

Comment: yeah its supposed to be n, i changed it.

Comment: Why  you are taking  input again for `n` inside while loop ?

Comment: Yeah I thought maybe that's a way to make the amount of elements in the output equal to n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way with comments

```
n = scanner.nextInt();
int viewNumber = 1;// for printing number
while (n > 0) {    // if any number printing left 
  for (int i = 1; i <= viewNumber; i++) { // This loop print viewNumber viewNumber's times
    System.out.print(viewNumber + " ");
    n--;           // decrease n value after printing a number
    if(n == 0) {   // break the loop if print n numbers already
      break;
    }
  }
  viewNumber++;    // increase view number after showing it's that times
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you, but following code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        while ((n = scanner.nextInt()) > 0) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < n && count < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= i && count < n; j++) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

should print this:

```
7
1 2 2 3 3 3 4
8
1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

Because I am assuming behavior from your example:

> For example, if n = 7, then the program should output 1 2 2 3 3 3 4.

I believe this could be rewritten to more efficient code (but more dirty code for you).

Answer (score 0):

Try This, I have used 2 for loops

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Please enter any digit");
            int n;
            n = scanner.nextInt();
            for(int a = 0;n>=a;a++) {
             
                for (int i = 0; a > i; i++) {
                    System.out.print(" "+a);
                
                }
            }
        }
```

Input: 5
Output: 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5